# ssh no username

Tags: networking, ssh, remote-access

I am trying to write some scripts and I have noticed that I can login on servers without username.
I have looked around and the answer was that both the localhost and the remote host should have the same user, but in my case this is not applicable.

For example the user in bash is `adlion` and in the remote host is `j-adlion`.

How is possible it know that should use `j-adlion` when in realty is even root user that can ssh.

I connect in the remote host using keys.

I thought it can be the key that was being specified only in the `j-adlion` and to test this I created the same `authorized_keys` for the root and it connect again to `j-adlion`.
When I run ssh in debug mode in one moment it says from nowhere using `j-adlion`.

Comment: What username do you use to login to the local computer? How do you know that your "bash" username is `adlion` and not `j-adlion`?

Comment: how I know that my bash username is `adlion` I change betwen `root´ and user by `sudo su´ for `root´ and `su adlion´ to go back as `adlion´ user And something else, usually bash has the prompt in form `username@host´ so I am sure that I am `adlion´ in `localhost´ and `j-adlion´ at the other I will try to setup two new VM just to test one more time and will give the steps.

Comment: This is happening only on my local machine.
Every time I try on some VM this problem do not exist.
Probably is the time to format my laptop.